# How to reset the month to date running total

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, business-intelligence

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    ACCOUNTDATE,
    PROPERTYNAME,
    rt.management
FROM 
    aaa t
CROSS APPLY
    (SELECT 
         SUM(MANAGEMENT) AS management
     FROM
         aaa
     WHERE
         PROPERTYNAME = t.PROPERTYNAME 
         AND ACCOUNTDATE <= t.ACCOUNTDATE) as rt
WHERE 
    AccountDate BETWEEN @STARTOFMONTH_MAN AND @ENDOFMONTH_MAN
ORDER BY 
    AccountDate
```

This is my query, I want to calculate the running total for month to date,
eg: The running total from `1/08/2016`-`31/08/2016` and again the total has to reset from the beginning for `1/09/2016`-`31/09/2016`.

But from the above query, I'm not able to reset total for the next month.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    ACCOUNTDATE
    ,PROPERTYNAME
    ,rt.management
from aaa t
cross apply     
    (select SUM(MANAGEMENT) as management
     from aaa
     where 
     PROPERTYNAME = t.PROPERTYNAME and
     ACCOUNTDATE BETWEEN dateadd(MONTH, datediff(MONTH, 0,t.ACCOUNTDATE),0) -- start of month
AND t.ACCOUNTDATE 
    ) as rt
WHERE AccountDate BETWEEN @STARTOFMONTH_MAN AND @ENDOFMONTH_MAN
ORDER BY AccountDate
```

Comment: I'm not sure how `datediff` works in SQL-Server . The difference in Month between `31-01-2016` and `01-02-2016` will be 1?

Comment: @sagi, it will be 1

Comment: How 5? No, I mean last day of a month and the first day of the next month ( 1 day difference but different month)

Comment: Yea for about 10 seconds :D, OK I just wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a running total, then in SQL Server 2012+, you would use:

```
select aaa.*,
       sum(management) over (partition by year(accountdate), month(accountdate)
                             order by accountdate
                            ) as rt
from aaa
where AccountDate between @STARTOFMONTH_MAN and @ENDOFMONTH_MAN
order by Accountdate;
```

In earlier versions, you would do this using `cross apply` and including the year and month in the logic:

```
SELECT t.*, rt.management
from aaa t cross apply     
     (select SUM(MANAGEMENT) as management
      from aaa t2
      where t2.PROPERTYNAME = t.PROPERTYNAME and
            year(t2.accountdate) = year(t.accountdate) and
            month(t2.accountdate) = month(t.accountdate) and
            t2.ACCOUNTDATE <= t.ACCOUNTDATE 
      ) rt
WHERE AccountDate BETWEEN @STARTOFMONTH_MAN AND @ENDOFMONTH_MAN
ORDER BY AccountDate;
```

Comment: thanks for your help.. but i'm using SQL server 2008.

Comment: @Swe . . . The second solution works with SQL Server 2008.

Comment: @gordon linoff, if we use month and year functions in where condition, then query performance will suffer or not?

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using SQL-Server 2012+ , you'll have to do it with a correlated query(or some kind of another join) :

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.ACCOUNTDATE
       ,t.PROPERTYNAME
       ,(SELECT SUM(s.MANAGMENT) FROM aaa s
         WHERE MONTH(t.accountdate) = MONTH(s.accountdate)
           AND YEAR(t.accountdate) = YEAR(s.accountdate)
           AND  s.PROPERTYNAME = t.PROPERTYNAME) as rt
from aaa t
WHERE t.AccountDate BETWEEN @STARTOFMONTH_MAN AND @ENDOFMONTH_MAN
ORDER BY t.AccountDate
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    ACCOUNTDATE
    ,PROPERTYNAME
    ,rt.management
from aaa t
cross apply     
    (select SUM(MANAGEMENT) as management
     from aaa
     where 
     PROPERTYNAME = t.PROPERTYNAME and
     ACCOUNTDATE BETWEEN dateadd(MONTH, datediff(MONTH, 0,t.ACCOUNTDATE),0) -- start of month
AND t.ACCOUNTDATE 
    ) as rt
WHERE AccountDate BETWEEN @STARTOFMONTH_MAN AND @ENDOFMONTH_MAN
ORDER BY AccountDate
```

Answer (score 0):

in order to always give running total for the month the item is in, try this - it avoids summing accounts from any previous months

```
    SELECT DISTINCT
    ACCOUNTDATE,
    PROPERTYNAME,
    rt.management
FROM 
    aaa t
CROSS APPLY
    (SELECT 
         SUM(MANAGEMENT) AS management
     FROM
         aaa
     WHERE
         PROPERTYNAME = t.PROPERTYNAME 
         AND ACCOUNTDATE <= t.ACCOUNTDATE 
         and MONTH(accountdate) = MONTH(t.accountdate) 
         and year(accountdate) = year(t.accountdate)) as rt
WHERE 
    AccountDate BETWEEN @STARTOFMONTH_MAN AND @ENDOFMONTH_MAN
ORDER BY 
    AccountDate
```

Try this for the financial year beginning April

```
    SELECT DISTINCT
    ACCOUNTDATE,
    PROPERTYNAME,
    rt.management,
    fy.managementFinancialYear
FROM 
    aaa t
CROSS APPLY
    (SELECT 
         SUM(MANAGEMENT) AS management
     FROM
         aaa
     WHERE
         PROPERTYNAME = t.PROPERTYNAME 
         AND ACCOUNTDATE <= t.ACCOUNTDATE 
         and MONTH(accountdate) = MONTH(t.accountdate) 
         and year(accountdate) = year(t.accountdate)) as rt
CROSS APPLY
    (SELECT 
         SUM(MANAGEMENT) AS managementFinancialYear
     FROM
         aaa
     WHERE
         PROPERTYNAME = t.PROPERTYNAME 
         AND ACCOUNTDATE <= t.ACCOUNTDATE 
         and (year(accountdate) * 12 + MONTH(accountdate) - 4) % 12  = (year(t.accountdate) * 12 + MONTH(t.accountdate) - 4) % 12 
         )as fy
WHERE 
    AccountDate BETWEEN @STARTOFMONTH_MAN AND @ENDOFMONTH_MAN
ORDER BY 
    AccountDate
```

Comment: for the same query, how can I get the running total for fiscal year? eg: from 01/04/2015-31/03/2016?